# Launch Solr Indexing in Nutch Source Code

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I am trying to index my Nutch crawl into solr, but inside of the source code, not from the command line.

I have created the following function

```
public static int runInjectSolr(String[] args, Properties prop) throws Exception{       
    String solrUrl = "http://ec2-X-X-X-X.compute-1.amazonaws.com/solr/collection1";

    String crawldb = JobBase.getParam(args,"crawldb", null, true);
    String segments = JobBase.getParam(args,"segments", null, true);
    String args2[] = {crawldb, segments};

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("-D solr.server.url",solrUrl);
    int code = ToolRunner.run(NutchConfiguration.create(),
            new IndexingJob(conf), args2);
    return code;
}
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
2013-08-07 19:37:13,338 ERROR org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter (main): Missing SOLR URL. Should be set via -D solr.server.url 
SOLRIndexWriter
solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
solr.auth.username : use authentication (default false)
solr.auth : username for authentication
solr.auth.password : password for authentication
```

So I am assuming I am not creating my configuration correctly. Any suggestions?

Or should I be passing my config field into run a different way? Maybe not using

```
NutchConfiguration.create()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. The `solr.server.url` must directly set in the configuration object not with -D option. The given message by nutch assumes running from command line and it is misleading here.
2. As you mentioned, you are passing two different configuration instances. the `NutchConfiguration.create()` creates a hadoop configuration internally and it adds some nutch specific resources to it so you don't need to create it by yourself. Also, the ToolRunner passes the conf object to IndexingJob so you don't need to pass it by its constructor.

So the correct code is:

```
Configuration conf = NutchConfiguration.create();
conf.set("solr.server.url", solrUrl);
ToolRunner.run(conf, new IndexingJob(), args2);
```